# Can I do calculation inside dimens.xml?

Tags: android

I just wondering can I do some calculations inside dimens.xml? I have tried it but doesn't work:

**dimens.xml**

```
<dimen name="wrap_content">-2dp</dimen>

<dimen name="width">@dimen/wrap_content * 0.5</dimen>
<dimen name="height">@dimen/wrap_content * 0.5</dimen>
```

**my_layout.xml**

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/main_right_menu_layout"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
    layout="@layout/main_right_menu_layout" />
```

Comment: doing programatically may be possible but I am not sure if you can do ti with in the xml.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The resources are resolved as the per the device and its orientation. Hence you cannot use references to other resources and have calculations on them in `dimens.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

No It is not possible to do in xml. But it can be done by java code.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more?